# Page layout breaks only in Opera which is weird?

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, opera

Okay so I'm working on an admin panel, in which everything should always be only within the view port until you hit the minimum widths and heights set.

The current version of it can be seen here (its still in development) : http://qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/Admin/

In layout terms, it works flawlessly in all browsers, even down to ie6 =D. However, opera doesn't like it, and for some reason, always add's extra space to the bottom of the page, making it have an extra scrollbar, and I can't fathom it out which is highly annoying.

Jquery is used to set the height of the container, sidebar, and content area so that they're always within the browser view port, and these functions rerun when the window is resized. I therefore cannot work out the the life of me what's wrong with opera.

Would anyone mind taking a look and seeing if they can work it out? =D

Comment: No idea what's wrong, but it's odd that it works perfectly whenever you use the mouse wheel when not over a text area, and only breaks things when you scroll with the mouse cursor over one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a design question than a programming question, but I did the following, and it seemed to help.

Removed `height:100%;` from the `html, body` selector, and added a few things:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    clip:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Seemed to help.

**docType** is a good site for design questions.

http://doctype.com

Comment: Thank you so much patrick, love you for this =D

And cheers for the link on docType, I was unaware that a Q&A community primarily for web designers existed =)

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `body{overflow:hidden}`?

Comment: Yeah, with no gain. It simply hid the scroll bar, but with the mousewheel, the gap was still there. Patrick has solved the problem now anyway, but thanks for you're help =)

Answer (score 0):

I see a sidebar for `<div id="content"/>`. could be that the element inline style you set `height:424px;` Try removing it and see if it works.